# Add classname comment template from functions.php

Tags: comments, variables, globals, comments-template

I want to add an extra classname to my `comment template` (the div wrapper before the post itself) which is stated in functions.php. The classname in functions.php is an extra field in my users profile section and I want to get that string and add it as an extra classname in my comment template.

The thing I want to add: `$cityofuser->user_city`

The question is: how do I do that? If I use `$classes[] = 'comment-author-' . sanitize_html_class(echo $cityofuser->user_city);`
in a template, it won't work. I get errors like `syntax error, unexpected 'echo'`

**Edit:**

In my register form, people can add info in a new field, stating the city they live in. I want to get this field's output, make it a new classname in the comment template and I want to change the background of the users post based on this classname. So the `custom field echo $cityofuser->user_city` that I have made *(in functions.php)* and added to my register pages, is something I want to use in my whole site.

I want to add the new class name in here:`<div id="comment-5" class="comment byuser comment-author-admin even thread-odd thread-alt depth-1">`

And after this is done, also on the posts. That must be something like `get_post_author?=cityofuser=Montreal` or something, but I don't have a clue how to do that.

Comment: It's not clear to me where you want to add this extra classname. For example you talk about some *post* and not a comment: "the div wrapper before the post itself". Can you show us an HTML example?

Comment: I edited my post. I hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should consider hooking into the [`comment_class()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_class) and [`post_class()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class) filters, if your theme supports it.

### Using the `comment_class` filter:

We can add the following filter:

```
/**
 * Add a custom comment class, based on a given comment author's user meta field.
 *
 * @see http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/170443/26350
 */

add_filter( 'comment_class', function( $classes, $class, $comment_id, $post_id ) {

    // Custom user meta key:
    $key = 'city';           // <-- Edit this to your needs!

    // Fetch the comment object:
    $comment = get_comment( $comment_id );

    // Check if the comment author is a registered user:
    if ( ! is_null( $comment ) && $comment->user_id > 0 )
    {
        // Check for the custom user meta:
        if( '' !== ( $value = get_user_meta( $comment->user_id, $key, true ) ) )
            $classes[] = sanitize_html_class( $value );
    }

    return $classes;
}, 10, 4 );
```

**Output example:**

```
<li class="comment byuser comment-author-someuser bypostauthor 
           odd alt depth-2 reykjavik" id="li-comment-78">
    <article id="comment-78" class="comment">
```

where the `reykjavik` has been added as the *city* user-meta, for the given comment author.

### Using the `post_class` filter:

Similarly for the `post_class` filter, we can use:

```
/**
 * Add a custom post class, based on a given post author's user meta field.
 *
 * @see http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/170443/26350
 */

add_filter( 'post_class', function( $classes, $class, $post_id ) {

    // Custom user meta key:
    $key = 'city';           // <-- Edit this to your needs!

    // Fetch the comment object:
    $post = get_post( $post_id );

    if( ! is_null( $post ) && $post->post_author > 0 )
    {
        // Check for the custom user meta:
        if( '' !== ( $value = get_user_meta( $post->post_author, $key, true ) ) )
            $classes[] = sanitize_html_class( $value );

    }

    return $classes;
}, 10, 3 );
```

Here's a shorter version that works within the loop:

```
/**
 * Add a custom post class, based on a given post author's user meta field.
 *
 * @see http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/170443/26350
 */

add_filter( 'post_class', function( $classes, $class, $post_id ) {

    // Custom user meta key:
    $key = 'city';           // <-- Edit this to your needs!

    // Check for the custom user meta:
    if( '' !== ( $value = get_the_author_meta( $key ) ) )
        $classes[] = sanitize_html_class( $value );

    return $classes;
});
```

**Output example:**

```
<article id="post-1" 
         class="post-1 post type-post status-publish format-standard 
                hentry category-uncategorized reykjavik">
```

where the `reykjavik` has been added as the last post class, based on our filter above.

Comment: Almost there! It now shoes me plain 'city' instead of the value that is put in by the users. How can I make that one dynamic?

Comment: Please check out the updated answer but it's untested.

Comment: This works, but not for the postauthor. Can you get that working too?

Comment: I can test it after 1 or 2 hours.

Comment: No problem. I will give you an upvote. You deserved this. PS: what do I have to change to get the post class also dynamically working? And can I use checkboxes / dropdowns / radio buttons too as the inputs? So instead of text, checkbox or whatsoever?

Comment: The post one does not work...

Comment: Are you using the `post_class()` function in your theme? The default themes are for example using it.

Comment: Yes, because this one: `add_filter( 'post_class', function( $classes, $class, $post_id ) {

    // your custom logic here
    $class[] = 'city';

    return $class;
}, 10, 3 );` gave me the class city, but it wasn't dynamic. The one you gave now does not show a new class at all.

Comment: ok, then we are close ;-) But the above `post_class` filter seems to works on my install. It fetches the given user meta for the post author and adds it to the post class output.

Comment: Close indeed... Weird, it doesn't on mine and I am sure I have implemented it well. What could be the problem?

Comment: Where does it break, i.e. can you check the output of each line? You could also simplify it by using the ` get_the_author_meta( $key )` function.

Comment: How do you mean? How can I check that? Is it because of the postauthor thing?

Comment: Check for example the value of `$post->post_author `, you could output it on your test install or add it to the class output. Guess it's better to continue this on [chat here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19235/discussion-between-siyah-and-birgire)

Comment: Yes, let's get this on chat :)